# Custom Post Type Causing Admin Sidebar UI Issue

Tags: custom-post-types, admin, admin-menu

I created custom type plugin, that if it is activated will make admin sidebar scroll follow along the admin screen height, instead of let it stuck.

What makes it doing like that?

Answer (score 0):

The WordPress admin menu scrolls with the page if its height exceeds the height of the window (ie. the menu doesn't fit on the screen). If you're adding custom post types then this could well happen, especially on smaller screens.

This is expected behaviour. You wouldn't be able to access the items at the bottom of the menu otherwise.